# What is this type of ornament, and how should it be played?

Tags: notation, ornaments

An appoggiatura is a grace note type ornament, that precedes main note it slurred to.  When it is played, it takes some time from the main note.

An appoggiatura looks like this :  and should be played something like this:
[image: appoggiatura]

---

In the piece below (JB Lœillet - Sonata III in F for Two Treble Recorders) there appears to be what looks like appoggiature, but (instead of preceding) succeeding the main note note they are slurred to:

[image: JB Lœillet - Sonata III in F for Two Treble Recorders]

---

What is this type of ornament called (is it a type of appoggiatura or some other type of grace note ornament)?

Is there another way to write this type of ornament?

It is just a way of ending a trill with a turn?

How should (a simple example of) this type of ornament be played?

---

**EDIT:**

Here is close-up of an incident of this ornament:

[image: close-up of an incident of ornament]

If I try to shorten the main note, to fit in both the two semiquavers on the left, And the three semiquavers on the right:  there is not enough time to fit them all into the time of the main crotchet note.

It doesn't make sense to treat the three tied grace note semiquavers on the right, as an appoggiatura like the two on the left.

Comment: Often the best way to answer these kind of questions (if you don't have a teacher to ask) is to find various recordings of other people playing the piece and see what they do!

Answer (score 1):

The first example is obviously a multi-note appoggiatura with the same properties of your simple example:

- Start on the beat of the main note
- shorten that accordingly to fit the ornament in.

You are probably right on the second example, the ornament is played after the trill but  the following notes and possible ornaments may influence this.

Comment: To be clear: both the lead 2-note appog. and the trailing 3-note appog should be inside the first quarter-note.

Comment: As for the first example (red circle) :  How can I fit five (two on the left, three on the right) semiquavers into the space of one crotchet?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace - Don't treat those note lengths in the ornament literally. Just make them short.